# Json request returning data in browser, but not in App

Tags: objective-c, xcode, json, asihttprequest

I have an ASIHTTPREQUEST querying a server which returns a JSON object. When I access the Url(http://xxxxxxxxxxx.xxx/xxxxx.json) via a browser, the JSON object is fine. However, when I request it in the app with

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:address]];
```

the JSON object structure is returned, but the values are all "can't be blank".

Anyone have any ideas as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sorted this by changing it to ASIHTTPRequest.